# BottomNavigation State gets lost after opening browser and then navigating back

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

Today, I discovered a very weird bug in my app. It goes the following: When the user navigates to the "profile screen", then opens the "information screen" and after that clicks on "agb", my app opens a browser and navigates the user to my website. Now the weird thing: When the user navigates back (to the "information screen", the bottomnavigation indicates, that he is currently on the home tab. Navigating back again (to the "profile screen"), then solves this issue. So it goes:

"Profile Screen" -> "Information Screen" -> Clicking on link -> "Opening Browser"
-> Clicking Back -> State gets lost -> "Information Screen" -> Clicking Back -> State gets restored -> "Profile Screen".

I added some pictures that show the error (red indicates the state, blue a action)

### Navigation

1. [Profile Screen (correct state)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsHtV.jpg)
2. [Information Screen (correct state)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC2yV.jpg)
3. [Browser (Probably state destroyed now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAAqj.jpg)
4. [Information Screen (state destroyed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kueGF.jpg)
5. [Profile Screen (state restored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkuUQ.jpg)

### Fragment (Information Screen)

```
class UserInformationFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_user_information) {
    private var _binding: FragmentUserInformationBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentUserInformationBinding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding  =  FragmentUserInformationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initUserToolbar()

        with(binding) {
            agbCv.setOnClickListener { startBrowser(INTERNET_AGB) }
            dataProtectionCv.setOnClickListener { startBrowser(INTERNET_DATA_PROTECTION) }
            impressumCv.setOnClickListener { startBrowser(INTERNET_IMPRESSUM) }
        }

    }

    private fun startBrowser(url: String) {
        val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(browserIntent)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

One Idea I had  was to set the state manually to the profile screen again after the user navigates back. But that would be a real mess and weird to do..

### Navigation Version

```
navigation_version = 2.3.5

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

Comment: I think you have to use deep link!

Comment: @miladsalimi For opening a browser?

Comment: No we set `Intent` for open the browser , for back from that URL to a specific fragment you should set the deep link.

Comment: @miladsalimi Could you introduce an example for me? I am not familiar with the concept of deep links. I especially don't know where to put this code (app or activity?)

Comment: Are you using navigation component?

Comment: @miladsalimi yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve this problem. The problem had nothing to do with  opening the browser, but with the recreation of my activity and reinflating of my bottomnavigation#menu. Before I had this:

```
private fun setUpBottomNav(newMenu: Int) {
    with(binding.bottomNavigationView) {
        menu.clear()
        inflateMenu(newMenu)
        setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment_container))
        // fix blinking when re selecting bottom nav item
        setOnItemReselectedListener {}
    }
}
```

The problem was that `setUpBottomNav()` was called, after getting back from the browser to my app, because the activity was recreated. The new solution is this:

```
private fun setUpBottomProfile(newMenu: Int) {
    val controller = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as NavHostFragment).navController

    with(binding.bottomNavigationView) {
        val currentSelectedItem = selectedItemId

        menu.clear()
        inflateMenu(newMenu)

        selectedItemId = currentSelectedItem

        setupWithNavController(controller)
        // fix blinking when re selecting bottom nav item
        setOnItemReselectedListener {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use Deep link.**

**Suppose that you have fragment one that you want to come back from browser to it.**

Add `deep link` tag to it like below:

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
    android:name="one"
    android:label="one"
     >

    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deepLink"
        app:uri="www.Deeplinkuri.com" />
    <action
  

</fragment>
```

You get **[www.Deeplinkuri.com](http://www.Deeplinkuri.com)** example **URI** from back end team and add to your `fragment`.

**You should ask a link from server side.**

**NOW WHEN YOU BACK FROM THE BROWSER YOU CAN OPEN YOUR OWN PAGE.**

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand this approach at all. The only thing I want is to open my website from my app and nothing more. My information fragment with its agb etc. has nothing to do with my website (there is no connection between my fragment and the website). The User first opens the app, then from their my website and when he navigates back, the bottomnavigation state should be restored, nothing more

Comment: And could you maybe add the fragment code for "fragment one"?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is keep your last selected state in local static variable and onResume() apply that selected state from the static variable.

```
companion object {
    const val LAST_SELECTED_STATE = SHOULD_BE_LAST_SELECTED_MENU_ID
}

override fun onResume() {
    yourBottomNavigation. setSelectedItemId = LAST_SELECTED_STATE
}
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same, but I would have to do this in 4 different fragments

Comment: Better to extract into BaseBottomNavigationFragment and extend it from all the fragment that you want to use.

Comment: But why do I have to do this in the first place?